# Unix ffmpeg Shell Script merge .aif and .mp4

Tags: scripting, osx

I need a script that merges multiple files (.aif and .mp4) in the same folder with the same name to a new folder called [original_name]_new.mp4

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash -e

function combine(){
    ffmpeg -i "$1" -i "$2" -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -acodec libfdk_aac -b:a 192k -vcodec copy -shortest "$3"
}

for video in ‘“*.mp4’; do
    name="{video%.*}
    audio=${name}.aif
    output=${name}_new.mp4
    combine $audio $video $output
done
```

And the output that I get:

```
Last login: Sun Oct 18 20:31:10 on ttys000
Tjalles-Mac-Pro:~ tjallo$ /Users/tjallo/Desktop/Christof/try1\ copy.command ; exit;
/Users/tjallo/Desktop/Christof/try1 copy.command: line 8: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
logout
```

[Process completed]

(Complete re-edit on 18-10-2015)

***Edit for @derobert:***
Now I have this as my code:

```
set -x
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e 
function combine(){
    ffmpeg -i "$1" -i "$2" -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -acodec libfdk_aac -b:a 192k -vcodec copy -shortest "$3"
}

for video in *.mp4; do
    name=“${video%.*}”
    audio=“${name}.aif”
    output=“${name}_new.mp4”
    combine "$audio" "$video" "$output"
done
```

And this as the Output:

```
Last login: Sun Oct 18 21:13:27 on ttys001
Tjalles-Mac-Pro:~ tjallo$ /Users/tjallo/Desktop/Christof/try1\ copy.command ; exit;
++ set -e
++ for video in '*.mp4'
++ name='“*”'
++ audio='““*”.aif”'
++ output='““*”_new.mp4”'
++ combine '““*”.aif”' '*.mp4' '““*”_new.mp4”'
++ ffmpeg -i '““*”.aif”' -i '*.mp4' -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -acodec libfdk_aac -b:a 192k -vcodec copy -shortest '““*”_new.mp4”'
ffmpeg version 2.8 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.8 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-opencl --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libxvid --enable-vda
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
““*”.aif”: No such file or directory
logout

[Process completed]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a few problems in the script:

As has been pointed out in the comments:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash -e
```

probably doesn't actually pass the `-e` option to bash. Instead, if you want that, put `set -e` below that line.

Next:

```
for video in ‘“*.mp4’; do
```

First, those are curly-quotes ‘, ’ and “ instead of straight-quotes ' and ". Depending on which font you're using that can be very hard to tell. Shell *always* uses the straight quotes. Second, `*.mp4` shouldn't be quoted at all. Quoting prevents expansion, and you'd like `*.mp4` to be expanded to all the `.mp4` files in the directory.

The next line has an error too, and this is the one the shell is complaining about:

```
name="{video%.*}
```

You're missing a close quote there.

The shell told you this, once you know how to read its error messages. First, you need to have numbered lines—I suggest looking for an option in your editor that shows you line numbers, or can jump to a line by number. To make it easy, I'll put them in below:

```
1    #!/usr/bin/env bash -e
2
3    function combine(){
4        ffmpeg -i "$1" -i "$2" -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -acodec libfdk_aac -b:a 192k -vcodec copy -shortest "$3"
5    }
6    
7    for video in ‘“*.mp4’; do
8        name="{video%.*}
9        audio=${name}.aif
10       output=${name}_new.mp4
11       combine $audio $video $output
12   done
```

The key to understanding that message is knowing that "EOF" means "end of file". So basically, the shell found a `"` on line 8. It kept looking for the matching `"` (to close the quote), but instead of finding one, it found the end of the file.

There is another problem:

```
combine $audio $video $output
```

Here, you want to pass those file names *without* any additional expansion or word splitting (otherwise file names with spaces in them will fail). So you need to quote those: `combine "$audio" "$video" "$output"`.

Finally, to debug your last issue: add a `set -x` at the top. That will cause the commands being executed to first be echoed out, so you can see what's going on.

**PS:** If you look at your [original question code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/236443/3), it doesn't many of these problems. Hence all the confusion.

### Curly quotes everywhere

[image: Picture showing curly quotes]

You need to get your editor to stop inserting curly quotes for you.

Comment: But after all this entering it still gives a error: *.aif file no such file or directory, as listed before. Appreciate all your help thanks.

Comment: @tjallo actually, I noticed another error... I've edited a fix for that one in. Also, try `set -x` to see why you're getting that *.aif error. Are you sure there are mp4 files in the current directory? And that you removed the quotes from `*.mp4`?

Comment: Added an edit because I didn't have enough space in comment.

Comment: @tjallo Your output shows `for video in '*.mp4'` ... You're not supposed to have (single) quotes there. Try `for video in *.mp4`. Also, that output shows a *lot* of curly quotes. Maybe your editor is putting them in for you...